# How to do math operations inside a function's parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'd like to multiply an incoming API price by 0.74. In the first parameter below I'd like to do a math operation.

Currently get the Typescript error `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type` when I try to do the math operation below.

```
// If current price is equal to USD, make the Canadian price appear instead.
if (curProduct.price?.currency !== "CAD") {
  curPrice = formatPrice(
    curProduct.price.text * 0.74, // error is here, also want to do math operation here.
    this.props.lang,
    true
  );
}
```

Comment: [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Presumably `curProduct.price.text` is text, not number. You can't multiply text by 0.74. Either convert this text to an int using `parseInt`, or use another field of `curProduct.price` which is already a number.

Comment: Thanks! Getting another error saying "Object is possibly 'null'", but at least I'm making progress.

Comment: I suggest you go find a decent basic javascript tutorial and study it until you actually understand it. Programming logic (despite popular belief it would seem) actually requires ... wait for it ... **THINKING**. Education will  provide you with the information necessary to be able to think about programming, instead of guessing about it.

Comment: @gforce301 Thanks for the tip, bud! :)

Comment: Hey you're welcome ... bud but don't listen to me. You can always spend days working on small language errors and posting in forums like this waiting for answers on things that you should have studied before you even tried to do anything more complicated than a "Hello World" demo. Just think at that rate maybe in 7 - 10 years you'll have a program that can do simple math!

Answer (score 1):

I assume `curProduct.price.text` is a string, as the keyword `text` indicates.

You can interpret the string as a number by setting the `+` beforehand.

```
// If current price is equal to USD, make the Canadian price appear instead.
if (curProduct.price?.currency !== "CAD") {
  curPrice = formatPrice(
    +(curProduct.price.text) * 0.74,
    this.props.lang,
    true
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried it, VS code automatically took away the brackets around curProduct.price.text on save. Getting an error now as well saying, "Object is possibly 'null'" on that piece of code too!

Comment: @JDFill Ok I just can't help myself. What is "VS code"? And those aren't "brackets" they're called parentheses.

Comment: @gforce301 Visual Studio Code = a lightweight free IDE